# Confusion between covariant and contravariant order of a $(n,m)$-tensor.

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, tensors, tensor-rank

I read various definitions for a tensor (and watched introduction videos), but still have a small confusion, where I kindly ask for clarification.

One definition that I really like and found often is:

> A $(n,m)$-tensor is a linear scalar function (an operator) that takes
> $n$ covectors and $m$ vectors in input to return a real number
> (scalar) as a result. It is covariant in $n$ components and contravariant in $m$ components *(which is still clear for me)*.

And now my confusion starts when reading the additional fact (see for example [this post](https://mathformachines.com/posts/a-tour-of-tensors/), [this post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-tensor-product-of-tensors-confusion.1005240/page-2) or [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.4558.pdf)):

> We say that a tensor has "type $(n,m)$” when it is of contravariant order $n$ and covariant order $m$.

Is there a simple explanation for this or I am just mixing $m$ with $n$?

In this context I ran into a related confusion: Not only in [this paper](https://www.math.lmu.de/%7Eleeb/lehre/texte/ana3/ana3_multilinalg.pdf) it is stated "Tensors of type $(1,0)$ are vectors. Tensors of type $(0, 1)$ are covectors". Contrary, in Johnston's book "Advanced Linear and Matrix Algebra" it is stated $(1,0)$-tensors are row vectors and $(0,1)$-tensors are column vectors. Usually row vectors are in the literature, as for example in [this post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/covariant-vs-contravariant.58257/), treated as covectors and column vectors are treated as (contravariant/tangent) vectors. There is even a Mnemonic given by [this post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/covariant-vs-contravariant.58257/): "covariant = row vector; because COvariant sounds like ROWvariant."

Comment: "It is covariant in n components and contravariant in m components "<-- This sentence is really setting you up for confusion. Disregard that sentence and you will be fine.  Always distinguish between the tensor itself, the *components* of the tensor and the *arguments* of the tensor. They are not the same. An $(n,m)$ has n contravariant indices and m covariant indices, $T^{j_1\dots j_n}_{k_1\dots k_n}.

Comment: Thank you - this helps already to divide things apart. So I conclude: A tensor taking $n$ covariant and $m$ contravariant arguments means that the tensor has contravariant order $n$ and covariant order $m$?

Comment: Yes. Exactly right. That is an $(n,m)$-tensor.

Comment: What I am asking myself is another weird thing: "Tensors of type $(1,0)$ are vectors. Tensors of type $(0, 1)$ are covectors" (https://www.math.lmu.de/~leeb/lehre/texte/ana3/ana3_multilinalg.pdf). And in the book "Advanced Linear and Matrix Algebra" it is written $(1,0)$-tensors are row vectors and $(0,1)$-tensors are column vectors. Usually row vectors are in the literature treated as covectors.

Comment: Well, its a matter of perspective. I'd say usually row vectors are treated like "normal" contravariant $(1,0)$ vectors. For instance, if A is a (nxn)-matrix and $x$ is an (nx1)-matrix (a row vector) you can use the usual rules of matrix algebra to form the valid expression $Ax=b$ where $b$ is another $(nx1)$-matrix, ie a row vector. If instead $x$ was a $(1xn)$ matrix (a column vector) the expression $Ax$ is no longer a valid matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That means it remains true that $(1,0)$-tensors are (contravariant) vectors, but we treat them as column vectors. And it remains true that $(0,1)$-tensors are  covectors and we treat these as row vectors?